# Devexpress button Disable button after the first postback occur

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Hot to disable devexpress button after first postback occur so user couldn't submit it twice.

I have tried to disable it with onClientClick event using javascript but that would also disable the button when some of validators is still not valid too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i use update panel as ajax call. i come across this way.

```
function pageLoad() {
    if (!Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(AjaxBegin);
    }
}

function AjaxBegin(sender, args) {
    btnxSignUp.SetEnabled(false);        
}
```

Comment: did you use ***UpdatePanel and Ajax*** ?